# Can't convert dataframe column data types

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, dask, data-conversion

After processing a big data set using Pandas/Dask, I saved the resulting data frame to a csv file.

When I try to read the output CSV using Dask, the data types are all objects by default. Whenever I try to convert them using conventional methods (e.g. defining data types while reading or reassigning them after reading) I keep getting errors regarding the conversion as seen below:

```
# ATTEMPT 1

import dask.dataframe as dd
header = ['colA', 'colB', ...]
dtypes = {'colA' : 'float', ...}
df = dd.read_csv('file.csv', names=header, dtype=types)

> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
> ...
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'colA'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ATTEMPT 2

import dask.dataframe as dd
header = ['colA', 'colB', ...]
df = dd.read_csv('file.csv', names=header)
df['colA'] = df['colA'].astype(str).astype(float)

> ...
> File "/home/routar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 730, in astype_nansafe
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'colA'
```

All the attributes in the original data frame (before converting to CSV) are ints/floats so the conversion is 100% possible. I'm also sure the values are valid.

I'm guessing this has something to do with Python's safe policy regarding data conversions.

Is there a workaround for this or any way to force the conversion?

Comment: Does your csv already contains the headers?

Comment: @mad_ It does. Already fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read dataframe from csv using `names=header`, you result with names of columns in your first line of your dataframe.

That's why you get the error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'colA'

Because `colA` is the first value of your column.

So just add `header=0` param to `read_csv` (to explicitly use first row as column names) to fix the problem:

```
df = dd.read_csv('file.csv', names=header, dtype=types, header=0)
```

Comment: Lol the error message lead me to think the issue lied on the column 'colA' instead of the actual value 'colA'. The types are now ok.